# Can't PUT to a Bucket

Tags: nosql, riak

First I'm pretty sure the riak is setting ok by using the command: `riak-admin status`

But I can't PUT in into a bucket test:

```
curl -v -X PUT -d 'This is really cool' -H "Content-Type: text/plain" http://markson.hk:8098/buckets/test/1234

< HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
< Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.9.0 (participate in the frantic)
< Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2011 12:13:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 193
```

Does the error due to the new bucket test? Should I create it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Basic Riak API Operations](http://wiki.basho.com/Basic-Riak-API-Operations.html), the basic PUT request looks like this:

```
PUT /riak/bucket/key
```

Hence your curl example should be similar to:

```
curl -v -X PUT -d 'The is so cool' -H "Content-Type: text/plain" http://markson.hk:8098/riak/test/1234
```

But then again, seems like somebody already deposited a test key for you:

[image]

Comment: @it actually did put the text into the bucket, it just didn't return the content unless you give the return=true